# How can i start the async task in wordpress for once?

Tags: php, wordpress

I wanna start the async task in wordpress after publish the post.

Currently i used `wp_schedule_single_event`, but i think this isn't good way to solve the solution.

is any body here that has the same problem ?

Comment: what's your async task? can't you use [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)

Comment: I know how can i use save_post but i wanna run tasks in save_post asyncly ( like a wp_cron jobs )

Comment: PHP don't support async task negatively, even wp_cron don't behave async. if you want to perform task only once then wp_cron is not good option.

Comment: What's your idea about that, what's the solution ?